# Extract Specific info from 'span' and 'td' anchor tags with Beautifulsoup

Tags: python-2.7

This question is kinda lame: I am using Beautiful soup on this website page, url = 'http://www.rentatbelleparkeast.com/Apartments/module/property_info/property%5Bid%5D/13578/' , to extract the following information.
1.  Name
2.  Address
3.  Phone
4.  Price of apartment (rent, Layout-Bed/Bath/Size.
I have the following simple code but I do not have the right anchor tags to extract the actual information. I am getting blank (none) in search results.

```
import urllib
from BeautifulSoup import *
url = 'http://www.rentatbelleparkeast.com/Apartments/module/property_info/property%5Bid%5D/13578/'
html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
#Create beautiful soup object
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
print soup
# Retrieve a list of the anchor tags
# Each tag is like a dictionary of HTML attributes
#For Phone I use tag 'span'
tag = soup('span')
#I search for Phone tag but this gives blank output
phone = soup.find(text= 'Phone: ')


# I use tag 'td' to get all information from the tables
tab = soup.findAll('td')
print tab # This gives the object with all information I need

#I extract, for example, Rent using the following loop. I get blank (None) results
for i in tab:
    print i.get('Rent *', None)
```

Comment: You are using `BeautifulSoup` version 3 which is very-very-very old. Please upgrade to `bs4`: `pip install beautifulsoup4` and change your import to `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple for name, address and phone u can use

```
name = ' '.join(soup.find('div', {'class': 'limitedTitle'}).text.split())
adress = ' '.join(soup.find('div', {'class': 'limitedText'}).text.split())
phone = ''.join(soup.find('div', {'class': 'propertyContactText'}).text.split())
```

Comment: I would like to generalize the search for the name, address, phone and rent for several urls (different websites). The above code is not able to parse the same information for the next url. Is there a standard tag (beautiful soup) that I can use to this data from a list of urls

Comment: Each tag/class name, etc, usualy vary from site to site. On the same site, when you are checking different subsites, it will be the same. But if I would like to create the tool, I would just go and create the class for parsing the text info, based on given attributes.